# Nginx proxy w/ modified URL

Tags: nginx

I am trying to make my website example1.com show the contents of example2.com. Basically, my goal is to create a proxy when /telehealth is visited but w/ a modified proxy manner. Such as when example1.com/telehealth/auth/sign-in is visited then it show the contents of example2.com/auth/sign-in. If you guys noticed, I removed the **telehealth** in the sub-path URL.

I tried the configuration below w/c is declared in nginx.conf

```
location ~ ^/telehealth/(.+)$ {
        proxy_redirect off;
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass http://example2.com/$1$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host example2.com;
}
```

What happens is it redirects w/ 301 status code to example2.com like example2.com/auth/sign-in/telehealth/auth/sign-in.

I wonder where I went wrong?